# unable to find an inherited method for function ‘lhs<-’ for signature ‘"NULL"’

Tags: r

I’m trying to use the "did" r package to do a did analysis with multiple groups and time of treatment. I use the mp.spatt function and using example provided In the R documentation:

```
data(mpdta)
out <- mp.spatt(lemp ~ treat, xformla=~lpop, data=mpdta,
                panel=TRUE, first.treat.name="first.treat",
                idname="countyreal", tname="year",
                bstrap=FALSE, se=TRUE, cband=FALSE)
## summarize the group-time average treatment effects
summary(out)
## summarize the aggregated treatment effect parameters
summary(out$aggte)
```

This example runs smoothly. However when removing the xformla=~lpop argument that is described as “A optional one sided formula” it seems to return the following error:

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘lhs<-’ for signature ‘"NULL"’

My code is this:

```
install.packages("did")
library("did")

data(mpdta)
out <- mp.spatt(lemp ~ treat, data=mpdta,
                panel=TRUE, first.treat.name="first.treat",
                idname="countyreal", tname="year",
                bstrap=FALSE, se=TRUE, cband=FALSE)
## summarize the group-time average treatment effects
summary(out)
## summarize the aggregated treatment effect parameters
summary(out$aggte)
```

if have tried to debug the code.The error occurs in line 28 and 29 in the compute.mp.spatt function i the package:

debug: pformla <- xformla

debug: formula.tools::lhs(pformla) <- as.name("G")

pformla is assigned a NULL and then lhs is using this NULL and the error occurs.

Am I doing something wrong here or can you recreate the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error in the package - i made the maintainer of the package aware and the bug has been fixed. As seen here - https://github.com/bcallaway11/did/issues/1